# How to create webservice for using all web languages

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services

I want to create a web service with asp.net and people that like to use this web service should add a html Code in their site.

My html code is

```
  <div>
           <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

In the web service I use ID for these Controls, how can I give my users a html code for the web service in all of the web languages they can use?

Comment: Use standard html rather than asp boxes and remember its not run at server your "webservice" needs to accept a post in from the remote pages

Comment: i want to use from value of text box in my web service classes

Comment: I think you need to go and read up and understand what a web service is.